# How to use Where Join Where?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list users who are from London and have NORMAL or GOLD membership type from my tables.

```
users table
====================
id  name   city_id  user_type
1   Helen  2        NA
2   James  1        PREMIUM
3   David  1        NORMAL

cities table
=============
id  name
1   London
2   New York


$londonUsers = $db->get_rows("
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE user_type = ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
    JOIN cities ON cities.id = users.city_id
    WHERE name = 'London'
");
```

Comment: I suggest you to read about the syntax of the [`SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). The answer is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put WHERE clauses after the FROM/JOIN statements. If you want more than one `WHERE`statement you can add them together with `AND` (the result of the clause in the `WHERE` statement should be `TRUE` or `FALSE` so you can combine statements using `AND` and `OR`).

Here is how you would do that in your example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
JOIN cities ON cities.id = users.city_id    
WHERE user_type IN ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
  AND cities.name = 'London'
```

This will first give you the joined table like this:

```
join table result
====================
users.id  users.name   users.city_id  users.user_type  cities.id  cities.name
1         Helen        2              NA               2          New York
2         James        1              PREMIUM          1          London
3         David        1              NORMAL           1          London
```

and then filter out to show only those that fulfil the WHERE statement i.e user_type NORMAL or PREMIUM and city London.

Comment: That sounds much better. However it gives me "Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error.

Comment: which one is correct? user_type = ('NORMAL','PREMIUM') or user_type IN ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')

Comment: It should be IN. Sorry, I simply used your query from the question and focused on moving the WHERE stuff. Fixed now so that it is working.

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it answers your question. :)

Answer (score 4):

SELECT, FROM, JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY.

Use "AND" or "OR" when combining multiple criteria in a where clause or on a join
and you can't use user_Type = two things.  you have to use an IN (this list) or create separate conditions. such as

`WHERE (user_type = 'NORMAL' or user_type = 'PREMIUM') and name = 'London'`

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM users u
 JOIN cities c
   ON c.id = u.city_id
 WHERE c.name = 'London'
   and u.user_type in ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
```

Comment: This will crash with `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous` as name exists in both tables.